# Understanding how One-BJT CW transceivers work

Tags: transistors, rf, oscillator, schematics

These days, I have been looking around some schematics for building a minimal CW transceiver. However, I do not fully understand their principle of operation.

As an example, here is the *Pititico* transceiver by PY2OHH:

[image: Pititico]

There are many similar designs around (see [the one by HA4OO](http://iz3ayq.blogspot.com/2020/02/1-bjt-transceiver-by-ha4oo.html) or [this list](https://a28.veron.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Minimalist_QRP_Book_V5.3-1.pdf)), but I prefer to focus on this one as of now in order to try to fully understand it.

As far as I know, in the previous schematic the crystal must act as the signal generator and, the BJT, as an amplifier (maybe a class-A amplifier, but I do not fully understand the feedback connecting the emitter with the base). C4 seems to me to be related with matching the output impedance of the antenna, but it is just a guess. U1 is a high impedance headphone and C3 is just a decoupling capacitor, and I cannot name the use of the rest of the components of this circuit which I am trying to decypher.

The thing I find the most disturbing on that schematic is how the separation between TX and RX is done. I read that the network C1-L1-C2 creates an *offset* of less than 1KHz to diplex both signals. How is this possible? Moreover, how is downconversion perfomed? Isn't there any mixer?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1:** Thank you to the people that answered; I know understand that the TX is a Pierce oscillator directly connected to the antenna, and that the RX acts as a regenerative receiver.

It would be great if someone could explain how TX and RX are combined, namely, how those capacitors (C1, C2 and C4) produce (demodulate in a direct downconversion) an offset signal at the headphone output.

Comment: Hmm. Have you read [this site about it?](https://wf7ihomebrew.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/py2ohhs-pititico-and-14-watt-but-no-rx/)

Comment: @jonk Yes! Thanks anyways!

Comment: Brief skim suggests: keying offsets signal by pulling crystal. If both parties tx on same frequency a 1 kHz shift mixes rx osc with far end tx and gives 1 kHz tone - useful for Morse code which is the intended use. Keying also increases oscillator power for tx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh man, there's so many things going on with that circuit...

The circuit is a Colpitts oscillator, always.

With the key up, the strength of the oscillation is severely limited by R2.  This does two things: it keeps you from getting nice QSL cards from the FCC for spurious emissions (maybe), and it lets signals coming in the antenna affect the strength of oscillation.  Note, however, that you still have an active oscillator connected to an antenna, so it *will* be radiating.  It's kind of a regenerative receiver with a crystal in it.  Received signals are rectified by Q1 (cringe) and appear in the headphones.

With the key down, oscillation amplitude goes up, and C2 is partially shorted by L1, and -- presto! -- you're transmitting a fairly strong signal.  Because L1 is now active in the circuit, the frequency of operation shifts slightly -- this means that someone talking to you on your frequency will be received as a tone in the receiver.

(Edited because I was originally looking at the wrong schematic)

At any rate - have fun, and stand in front of he mirror practicing saying "yes sir and/or madam, I will stop using that transmitting equipment immediately!".

Comment: During receive it acts as a direct conversion receiver with mixing occurring between the oscillating frequency and the incomong signal, it doesn't need to vary the oscillation amplitude - the difference frequency is in the audio band (depends upon the oscillation frequency shift between Tx and Rx).

Comment: Thank you for the explaination! I have a couple more doubts. First, don't Colpitts oscillators do not normally include any feedbak between the Emitter and Base of the BJT, while this schematics includes C1. Why is this for? Second one, how is the demodulation performed at Q1? (cringe)

Comment: And why should not I use it as a transmitter? If it does not saturate, it should not produce excessive harmonics; maybe just a slow frequency drift

Comment: @user3141592 - it's more like a Pierce oscillator with the ground moved to the collector.

Comment: C1, C2 and X1 form a classic common-collector Colpitts oscillator.  L1 is just there to confuse the tourists.

Comment: @user3141592 it's fine as a transmitter -- it's just that it will transmit (weakly) in receive.

Comment: Thank you very much both you and @KevinWhite for the information about the transmitting side! How does the direct downconversion work there? And how is the offset between TX and RX implemented?

Comment: The key phrase is "regenerative receiver", which you can search for.  Basically, receiving a signal close to the oscillator frequency shifts the oscillator's operating point as the received signal goes into and out of phase with the oscillation.  This generates a tone in the headset.

Comment: @user3141592. There is no rx/tx offset - it is direct conversion. With a superhet you have the IF offset for the rx.

Comment: There is no RX/TX offset, but in order to receive a tone on the transmit frequency, the oscillator frequency has to be shifted.  Hence L1.